# How can I get the CardView from a clicked widget?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In an Android app I have a `RecyclerView` and a `CardView` with a layout like the following:

```
CardView
    |
    +-- LinearLayout (H)
           |
           +-- ImageView[onclick=advance]
           |
           +-- LinearLayout (V)
                   |
                   +-- TextView
                   |
                   +-- TextView
```

When a user clicks the `ImageView`, I want to call a method on the corresponding `Adapter` with the index of the clicked `CardView`. Using `RecyclerView.getChildPosition` I can get that index. *However*, the click handler for the `ImageView` gets a reference to the `ImageView`. Not the `CardView`.

So my code currently looks like this:

```
public void advance(View v) {
    Log.v(TAG, String.format("Determining position of %s", v));
    // TODO this "getParent" daisy-chain is really ugly. There must be a better way!
    LinearLayout p1 = (LinearLayout) v.getParent();
    CardView p2 = (CardView) p1.getParent();
    int pos = mRecyclerView.getChildPosition(p2);
    mAdapter.advance(pos);
}
```

This *works*, but is 100% coupled to the layout (not only structure, but also classes). If I change the layout, I need to change the code. Is there not a way to get directly at the `CardView`?

Comment: Not sure if this works but, what about 2 custom views (MyTextView and MyCardView) and a interface between them to handle the communication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't worked much with `RecyclerView` so far, and my guess is the same simple logic as in `ListView` can be applied here as well:

in you `RecyclerView.Adapter`

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    // set on click for you imageView
    holder.mImageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View yourImageView) {
            // position here is the position of CardView
            advance(position); // advance from adapter
        }
    });
}
```

Please let me know if it makes sense.

Comment: Thank you. This is indeed a much cleaner solution.

Comment: @exhuma I think it should be more reliable to change last line to : `advance(holder.getAdapterPosition())`, see *onBindViewHolder* description on [this page](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html). Actually, you can even move this whole "setOnClickListener" to onCeateViewHolder this way.